# web and mail server under same ip with different names

Tags: dns, webserver, mail-server, hosting

i have followed this [**Digital Ocean Mail-in-a-box**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-your-own-mail-server-with-mail-in-a-box-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to set up Mail server in existing Web server.

```
hostname: box.somename.com
```

i also have domain with

```
Domain name: www.somename.com
Name servers: ns1.box.somename.com and ns2.box.somename.com
Host Names: ns1.box ip_address and ns2.box ip_address
A Record: ip_address
```

after installing mail server (successfully) my domain `www.somename.com` is pointing to mail server landing page. but i want it to be separate like

```
www.somename.com  --> normal web app hosted in same server (using ngnix)

box.somename.com --> mail server landing/admin page
```

how can i achieve this.

Comment: you can try a different port or sub domain for mail

Comment: yes i'm using subdomain for mail `box.somename.com` but the problem is both `box.somename.com` and `somename.com` are landing on same page which is mail-in-a-box homepage

Comment: setup a virtual host for mail

Comment: hmm sorry im new to this sever things. can you please explain in detail or point me to a helpful resource

Comment: Refer to virtual host section here

Answer (score 0):

In the admin dashboard, navigate to 'Web' and click 'Change' next to the domain you want to change. This will bring up a dialog box that instructs on where the new directory for the domain will be located. Click 'Update' to make the change.